# Cant connect to Postgresql server running in a Windows 10 virtual machine

Tags: linux, postgresql, windows, database-connection, virtualbox

I'm running a Postgres server in a windows 10 virtual machine on my pop-os laptop. I'm trying to connect to it from my host OS (Linux). In a virtual box I created a port forwarding rule:

[image]

I also changed the listening port in the Postgres configuration to equal '*'.

The error message I get trying to connect is this:

```
postgres@pop-os:/home/peyton$ psql -p 5432
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't understand this very well so I could really use some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

`psql -p 5432`

is saying connect to local socket on Linux machine. Per the error message:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

You need to do something like:

`psql -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1`